# Why count differs between ls and ls -l linux command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command

I had a directory with number of files and need to check the count of files present in it.

I tried the following two commands:

```
ls | wc -l
ls -l | wc -l
```

and found there are differences while using both commands. (ie. number of files is greater in the usage of second command while comparing to the first command.)

I would like to know the changes happening in the both commands.

Comment: If possible please provide command output. "ls -l | wc -l" showing 1+ count as comapred to "ls | wc -l"  is expected.

Comment: look at the outputs from the commands. ls -l will have a line at the top saying total.

Comment: You can find out yourself. Do a `ls > file1.txt` and `ls -l > fiile2.txt` and then compare the files to see what's happening (e.g. `diff file1.txt file2.txt`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man ls`:

```
-l      (The lowercase letter ``ell''.)  List in long format.  (See below.)  If the output is to a terminal, a total sum for all the file sizes is output on a line before the
         long listing.
```

So `ls -l` adds a header line stating the "total" size of files:

```
$ ls -l /
total 65
-r--r--r--   1 root  wheel  6197 May 11 21:57 COPYRIGHT
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel  1024 Jun  1 16:02 bin
drwxr-xr-x   9 root  wheel  1536 Jun  1 16:02 boot
dr-xr-xr-x   8 root  wheel   512 Jul  7 20:16 dev
.......
```